# Get index of rows which matches certain value for whole dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas DataFrame with floats.

Sample data:

```
        -100   -99   -98 ... 0    1    2    3 
-100    0.00  0.00  7.21    99  0.00   99   99
-99     0.00  0.00  7.21    99  0.00   99   99
-98     3.55  3.55  7.21    99  0.00   99   99
...
0       6.55  7.21  7.21    14  0.00   99   0.00
1       6.55  7.21  7.21    14  0.00  0.00  0.00
2       6.55  7.21  7.21    14  0.00  0.00  0.00
3       6.55  7.21  7.21    14  0.00  0.00  0.00
```

Name of columns are integers:

```
       df.columns 
[out]: Int64Index([-100,  -99,  -98,  -97,  -96,  -95,  -94,  -93,  -92,  -91,
        ...
          91,   92,   93,   94,   95,   96,   97,   98,   99,  100],
       dtype='int64', length=201)
```

The same for index:

```
       df.index 
[out]: Int64Index([-100,  -99,  -98,  -97,  -96,  -95,  -94,  -93,  -92,  -91,
        ...
          91,   92,   93,   94,   95,   96,   97,   98,   99],
       dtype='int64', length=200)
```

I'm trying to get columns and indices where highest value occurs (99) in this dataframe.
For columns I used:

```
       columns_with_value = df.columns[(df == df.max().max()).iloc[0]]
       list(columns)
[out]: [0,2,3]
```

and its working correctly (I checked manually in dataframe)

I would like to get the same output for index.

I tried:

```
index = df[df == df.max().max()].index.values.astype(int)
```

But it returns all of indexes from -100 to 99 which is no correct
there are rows without maximal value.

I tried also with defining columns like in most typical example:

```
df.loc[df[columns_with_value] == df.max().max()]
```

And its returns ValueError: `Cannot index with multidimensional key`

The correct output for sample data would be:

```
[out]: [-100, -99, -98, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`, if I undersand you correctly:

```
r, c = np.where(df == df.to_numpy().max())
```

This will return the index of every row and column in the dataframe that 99.

Now, using

```
indx = df.index[r]
cols = df.columns[c]
```

To get the labelled integers. And you, can `zip` to get (r,c) coordinates.

```
coords = list(zip(indx, cols))
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem, it returns repeated values so I just add `indx.unique` to get my desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can do `stack`

```
idx = df[df == df.max().max()].stack().index[0][0]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately this returns only one value. While  `idx = df[df == df.max().max()].stack().index[0]` result is tuple: (-100, 1) so it is incorrect, by checking manually I see that some rows shouldn't be returned.

Comment: @Aly please show what you need and your sample data , so we can better  address the issue